# Chrome vs. IE/FF CSS height 100% Issue

Tags: html, css, firefox

My DIV (used as navigation) is not using Height: 100% when                   using IE or FF. Chrome works fine.

- I did research and I tried using `position: absolute;` on different and multiple DIVs, but this never fixed it for me.
- In my opinion body and html height is set to 100% (`html, body { height: 100%; }`).
- Clearfix doesn't work for me either ([stackoverflow - clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633516/css-height100-issue)).
- Working with a `overflow: hidden;` couldn't help me.

I really wanna understand this issue, and I really try to unterstand while doing research, but i don't get it. Following: Jsfiddle, CSS & HTML Code, 2 Screenshots (Chrome and FF)

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nqsto6r9/4/

**My CSS:**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
}

body { margin: 0 auto; }

button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 154px;
}

input {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 140px;
}

select {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 154px;
}

#content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 170px);
}

#content_header {
  background-color: #4C587E;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: #3761A7;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#header_span {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#inner_content {
  max-width: 1024px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  margin-left: 0.5cm;
  margin-right: 0.5cm;
  margin-top: 0.5cm;
  width: calc(100% - 1cm);
}

#nav {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 150px;
}

#wrapper {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#wrapper_nav {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
  width: 170px;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
        <span id="header_span" class="header_h1"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper_nav">
            <div id="nav">
                <a href=".html" class="nav_links">1</a><br />
                <hr>
                <a href=".html" class="nav_links">2</a><br />
                <hr>
                <a href=".html" class="nav_links">3</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="inner_content">
              asda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
              adasda<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Chrome (What I want):
[image]

Firefox (What I need to fix):
[image]

**Thanks in advice.**

**Update**
Right now using [CSS display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) & [CSS display Property - Playit](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=inline) to understand it ...

**Update2 - Solution**
Someone posted me the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqsto6r9/7/) which I tried to understand before. I need to change:

```
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 170px);
}
#wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper_nav {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
    width: 170px;
}
```

into

```
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#wrapper_nav {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 170px;
}
```

Comment: I think it's also wrong in Chrome. The left nav is 100% high, but that element is below the header bar, so you're occupying more space than is in your viewport. I would suggest to just use a JavaScript calculation.

Comment: I always want the gray navigation background being 100% height even if I only got 3 entries in there. I hope I understood you.

Comment: I don't think that's what you want. You want the left nav to fill out the _remainder_ of the page, that's not what `height: 100%` does.

Comment: In my opinion html & body presentate the complete view of the website. If I  got a div like my nav on the left and I use height: 100% I'd expect it does wrap the content, or does fill the complete view. But in case that my inner_content is using the same css attributes, both should behave the same. Doesn't it?

Comment: cm is for print, not a monitor. Your browser has no concept of size measurement on a monitor.

Comment: You're using cm as a measurement in one of your rules, cm = centimetres.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html so I don't have to repeat myself.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks didn't thoguht about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
Someone posted me the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqsto6r9/7/) which I tried to understand before. I need to change:

```
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 170px);
}
#wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper_nav {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
    width: 170px;
}
```

into

```
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#wrapper_nav {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 170px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I took the liberty of cleaning up some of your code. As it was supplied, you had a lot of redundant nesting in your HTML and you were overusing the `float` property in your CSS.

To your specific problem, one solution is, instead of setting the `height` of your `body` and `html` to `100%` and then floating your nav, try setting the `position` of your `body` to relative and then positioning your nav absolutely. Setting the `top` *and* `bottom` properties allows you to create the height you want.

You'll also need to adjust some of your other styles to reflect this change.

**EXAMPLE**

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
body{
    background:#fff;
    font-family:arial;
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    min-width:1280px;
}
#content{
    margin:0 0 0 170px;
    padding:20px;
    max-width:1024px;
}
#header{
    background-color:#3761A7;
    height:40px;
}
#nav{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding:30px 10px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    width:170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="nav">
    <a href=".html" class="nav_links">1</a><br>
    <hr>
 <a href=".html" class="nav_links">2</a><br>
    <hr>
 <a href=".html" class="nav_links">3</a><br>
</div>
<div id="content">adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br>adasda<br></div>
```

Comment: Did you edited your post? I'm not sure but someone posted me this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqsto6r9/7/) and this seems to work fine too. Anyway, thank you.